# When would the inner product be non symmetric over the reals?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

For example the inner product where $u=(u_1,u_2) , v=(v_1,v_2)$                       is $\left<u,v\right>= 3u_1v_2 + u_2v_1$ How would you prove that it is not symmetric.

Thanks

Comment: (Real) inner products are, by definition, symmetric.

Comment: @RAIashi Does your text define an inner product using only bilinearity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\langle u,v\rangle=3u_1v_2+u_2v_1$ can be shown not to be symmetric by simply plugging in some values. For example, taking $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ it is clear that
$$\langle(1,0),(0,1)\rangle\neq\langle(0,1),(1,0)\rangle.$$
Do note that this function does *not* define an inner product; it is not (conjugate) symmetric, and it is not positive definite.